# NFA to Regular Expression

Tags: regex, nfa

I have a picture of an NFA, and need to get the resulting regular expression from the NFA. I first had a*b*a*, but realized this doesn't work. I believe it must start with (a|b), but am not sure where to go from there.

[image: NFA]

Comment: SO is not a test/homework answering service.

Comment: @torazaburo it is a practice test review. If you would like a picture of that too I can show you that.

Comment: it remembers my college days :)

Comment: I remember having to answer this exact question, with the same NFA, on a test two years ago at Drexel University. Unfortunately I don’t remember how I answered it.

Comment: My old textbook, which describes the process for questions like this, is free. Download chapter 10 of *[Foundations of Computer Science](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/focs.html)* by Aho and Ullman, and then read section 10.9 “From Automata to Regular Expressions”. It describes an algorithmic way to eliminate states one by one, while turning each path label into a regular rexpression. Eventually you are left with just two states and four paths with regexes, and you can combine those four regexes according to a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are general approaches on how to translate an NFA to a regular expression, but I do not remember how.  However in your case we are helped by the fact that all loops of length more than 1 starts in state 0.  So we can use the following regexp;

```
(b?ab|aab|ab+aa?b)*(ba?|aa|ab+aa?)
```

Explanation;

`(b?ab|aab|ab+aa?b)*` is what the regexp would be if state 0 was the only matching state.  Since all long loops goes through state 0 this is a prefix of our regexp.

`(ba?|aa|ab+aa?)` is what our regexp would be if the b links going back to state 0(from state 1 and state 4) where not present.  Because we are in state 0 after the previous loop this takes us to an accepting state.

Bringing the two together we have a regexp that looks for traces that goes returns to state 0 an arbitrary number of times and then move from state 0 to an accepting state.

Starting with `(a|b)` is the wrong approach, because the states 1 and 3 have little in common and how you are allowed to proceed from an a is different from how you are allowed to proceed from a b.